# How do I do string substitution in a query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I am trying to dynamically generate some sqlalchemy queries in Pyramid.

```
queries=[]
if var1=='1':
  queries.append("Table.name.in_(['Dave'])")
if var2=='2':
  queries.append("Table.last_name.in_(['Thomas'])") 

qq = (','.join(queries))

if len(queries) > 1:
  query = DBSession.query(Table).filter(and_('%s')) % qq
else:
  query = DBSession.query(Table).filter('%s') % qq
```

I get an error: `"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'Query' and 'str'"`
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case above, it looks like the string you're passing in is not in the proper position and is instead trying to pass the string into the Query object that comes from `DBSession.query()`. Try this:

```
if len(queries) > 1:
  query = DBSession.query(Table).filter(and_('%s' % qq))
else:
  query = DBSession.query(Table).filter('%s' % qq)
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
DBSession.query(Table).filter(and_('%s')) % qq
```

applies the `% qq` to the entire result of `filter` - you only want to apply it to the string passed in as an argument:

```
DBSession.query(Table).filter(and_('%s' % qq))
```

But there's no reason to use formatting here - just pass the string in directly:

```
DBSession.query(Table).filter(and_(qq))
```

Note that using Python's string formatting does *not* avoid the potential sql injection attacks if `qq` contained anything generated from user input.